# .htaccess: Add optional language parameter to all pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

I have a `.htaccess` file rewriting all URLs. For example:

```
# Special urls
RewriteRule ^(article)/([^/]*)(?:/[^/]*)?$ /index.php?page=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(privacy)$ /index.php?page=legal&type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(imprint)$ /index.php?page=legal&type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# All urls
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\s]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Now I want to integrate a language parameter in my URL. For example

- `example.com/test` ➡ `/index.php?page=test`
- `example.com/en/test` ➡ `/index.php?lang=en&page=test`

How would I accomplish this without having to edit all `RewriteRule`s? Is there a way to check if the part after `example.com` matches a regex, append a query parameter and handle all future rules normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Add the following rule *before* your existing rules:

```
# Add optional language URL param if present in the first path segment
RewriteRule ^(\w\w)/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [QSA,DPI]
```

**UPDATE:** The `DPI` flag discards the original path-info that would otherwise be appended to the URL-path after the rewrite. This would result in the directives that immediately follow from failing to match, until the next round of processing. (See *update* below that goes into more detail.)

This assumes that the language code is always 2 characters.

The URL is rewritten to *remove* the language path segment from the URL-path and appends this as a `lang` URL parameter. The `L` flag is specifically omitted so the following rules are left to match the URL-path without the language code.

Since the following rules already have the `QSA` flag then the `lang=` URL parameter is appended.

Note, however, that the `lang=en` parameter is appended at the end of the query string, not prefixed to the beginning, as in your example.

---

> **UPDATE:** It seems like not only the language gets appended, but also the page name. For example: `example.com/de/index` results in `index?lang=de/index`
> Solved by adding DPI to `[QSA]` ➡ `[QSA,DPI]`

Hhhmmm, yes and no... given only the directives as stated in the question this should still "work" without the `DPI` flag (although not as efficiently). In fact, `index?lang=de/index` does not seem to be possible as a resulting URL (there's no `page` URL parameter)? It's possible that other directives are perhaps resulting in the *path-info* being appended to the query string? One thing of note is that the last rule stated in the question is missing the `L` flag, so any directives that follow are perhaps being unnecessarily processed (and even conflicting). However, the `DPI` flag is certainly an improvement here and should be added.

In detail...

Given a request of the form `/de/index`, and `/de` does not exist as a physical directory, then the `/index` part on the end of the requested URL-path is *additional pathname information* (path-info) and this is appended to the URL-path after the rewrite above (which is indeed undesirable). So, a request of the form `/de/index` is rewritten to `index?lang=de`, which becomes `index/index?lang=de` after the path-info is re-appended (note that it's not appended to the query string).

The resulting URL-path `index/index` (with appended *path-info*) fails to match the `RewriteRule` directives that follow. However, the rewrite engine then *starts over*, at which point the path-info that was (unnecessarily) added is then naturally discarded before the next round of processing. This results in the "correct" `index?lang=de` URL being used as the input for the second round of processing. This matches the last rule stated in the question and the request is finally rewritten to `/index.php?page=index&lang=de`.

So, the `DPI` flag shouldn't strictly be necessary here for it to "work". However, it is certainly recommended as it avoids the unnecessary 2nd pass through the rewrite engine. With the `DPI` flag, the path-info is not appended after the first rewrite, so the URL-path would match the appropriate rule on the first pass.

Comment: It works almost, with the exception of a small problem. It seems like not only the language gets appended, but also the page name. For example:
`example.com/de/index` results in `index?lang=de/index`

I've used the following code to debug:
`RewriteRule ^(\w\w)/(.*) $2&lang=($1) [QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vardump
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1?vardump&thereq=%{THE_REQUEST}&reqhost=%{HTTP_HOST} [R=302,L,QSA]`

It outputs, that this is the result of my RewriteRule: `index&lang=(de)/index`
(I added the parenthesis to debug).

Comment: Solved by adding DPI to [QSA] ➡ [QSA,DPI]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Interesting. Whilst the the `DPI` flag is certainly an improvement, this shouldn't strictly be necessary for the limited example posted in the question - it works as intended on my dev server (and I'm unable to reproduce quite the same behaviour you are seeing). It's possible there is an additional conflict with other directives? Also, what version of Apache are you on? I've updated my answer, added the `DPI` flag and attempted to explain what is going on.